# Java: Reference from a non-static comparator to it's outer class field

Tags: java, reference, comparator

I need to sort lists of objects with a non-static comparator that uses a value from it's outer object field.

```
class A {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Comparator<A> scoreComparator = new Comparator<A>() {
        public compare(A o1, A o2) {
            // System.out.println("this: " + this);
            return (int) (x * o1.x - x * o2.x);
        }
    }

    public A(int _x, int _y, int _z) {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        z = _z;
    }
}

A var_1 = new A(1, 2, 3);
A var_2 = new A(5, 6, 7);
List<A> list = getMyListFromSomewhere();

// the following will produce different ordering
Collections.sort(list, var_1.scoreComparator);
Collections.sort(list, var_2.scoreComparator);
```

But for some reason this does not work properly. When I uncomment the println line in the comparator, it shows that the references are to A objects, but they are different within one sort() call, therefore the value of "x" is different. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why do you need the `Comparator`to be non-static? Why not just the following?

```
    static class MyComparator implements Comparator {
        public compare(A o1, A o2) {
            // System.out.println("this: " + this);
            return o1.x - o2.x;
        }
    }

    public Comparator scoreComparator = new MyComparator();
```

Comment: Your example does not account for the internal state of another object. What I want to achieve is different ordering depending on what instance of A I take as a "base". For example: I have objects v1 and v2 - both instances of A. I have a list [v3, v4, v5]. When I sort with a "base" v1, I get [v4, v5, v1], when I sort "based" on v2 I get [v5, v1, v4]. The order of the sorted list depends on internal field values of v1 and v2 respectively.

Comment: And anyway I would make the comparator a static class and would pass "x" as a paremeter to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to achieve. The code above doesn't work because you use different values of `x` when you create your `A` instances.

Each time, you create an instance of `A`, you also create an instance of the comparator which is tied to the instance of `A`. That means the `x` in the `compare()` method is either `o1.x` or `o2.x`.

I suggest to create a new class that implements the comparator and which has a field `x` to make it independent of `A`:

```
public class ScoreComparator implements new Comparator<A>() {
    private int x;
    public ScoreComparator(int x) { this.x = x; }
    public compare(A o1, A o2) {
        // System.out.println("this: " + this);
        return (int) (x * o1.x - x * o2.x);
    }
}
```

Comment: "That means the x in the compare() method is either o1.x or o2.x." -- Didn't get this?!

Comment: When I pass "var_1.scoreComparator" as my comparator, doesn't that have a reference to var_1 already? So when JVM looks at "(x * o1.x - x * o2.x)" it would translate it to "(var_1.x * o1.x - var_1.x * o2.x)". Isn't it how it works?

Comment: I reread your comment and I think your solution will work great for me. I can certainly pass the value of "x" to the comparator. Thank you! But I still do not understand why my solution didn't work out.

Comment: As for my comment: When you create an `var_1`, you also get a comparator for `var_1`. In this comparator, you access `var_1.x`. When you sort the list containing `var_1` and `var_2` using the comparator from `var_1`, then you will get a call to `compare()` with `var_1` and `var_2` as the values of the parameters. That means the `return` becomes `var_1.x * var_1.x - var_1.x * var_2.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see first what the `scoreComparator` does. The line

```
(int) (x * o1.x - x * o2.x)
```

could be also written as

```
(int) x * (o1.x - o2.x)
```

which means the the sign of `x` -- positive or negative inverts comparation result will revert the ordering in the sorting list.

Casting to `int` is added to ensure integer overflow if values of `x` and `o1.x` or `x` and `o2.x` are too big. Again, the sign of `x` will just revert the ordering.

Since both `var_1` and `var_2` have positive values for the field `x` we can conclude that the second scenario causes integer overflow and different ordering. `var_1.x` equals to `1`, and `var_2.x` equals to `5` which makes integer overflowing five times more probable in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve by this design, but this is a very bad design. **If you want a non-static comparator inside the same class type, try going for compareTo rather than compare. Otherwise, put the compare method in a separate class as @Aaron suggested.**